# Setting property in backing bean while navigating from one page to another (View Scope) doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I have a backing bean `Authority` in the view scope and I have two pages `viewRoles` and `editRole` mapped to this backing bean.

In the `viewRoles` page there's a link to go to `editRole` page:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="#{au.displayName}" action="pretty:editRole">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{authority.authorityId}" value="#{au.id}"/>                   
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

It navigates to the other page, but the property is not getting set, even though the bean is in the view scope and the both pages are mapped to the same backing bean. It only works when I change the view scope to session scope.

Note: my beans are managed by Spring, also this view scope is not the JSF default `@ViewScoped`, it's a custom one which I found on http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/. Also I am using PrettyFaces to manage my navigation.

The question is, is the above scenario supposed to work with a real JSF2 `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` or is the problem related to Spring or another problem?
please advise.

Comment: Same question posted at http://ocpsoft.com/support/topic/setting-property-in-backing-bean-while-navigating-from-one-page-to-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this will also not work with a JSF2 [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) bean. You're basically navigating to a *different* view. A [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) bean lives as long as you're interacting with the *same* view by returning `null` or `void` in the action methods. Using [`<f:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) in the command link in combination with [`<f:viewParam>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) in the target view should do it.

E.g. in the command link:

```html
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="#{au.displayName}" action="pretty:editRole">
    <f:param name="authorityId" value="#{au.id}"/>                   
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

and in the target view:

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="authorityId" value="#{authority.authorityId}"
        required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid page access. Please use a link from within the system."
    />
</f:metadata>
```